# More than one gridview with one adapter

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-gridview

im making an application with lots of images on my Activity i have 11 gridview. The problem is for each gridview i'll have to make a new Adapter to populate images i'm looking for a way to populate each Gridview using one Adapter to show different stack of images ! is it possible im new to android so i don't have a clue what to search for this

Thanks

Edit: heres my code for one adapter that

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.pic76, R.drawable.pic87,
        R.drawable.pic77, R.drawable.pic88,
        R.drawable.pic78, R.drawable.pic89,
        R.drawable.pic79, R.drawable.pic90,
        R.drawable.pic80, R.drawable.pic91,
        R.drawable.pic81, R.drawable.pic82,
        R.drawable.pic82, 
        R.drawable.pic83, 
        R.drawable.pic84, 
        R.drawable.pic85, 
        R.drawable.pic86
};
```

you can see i have hard coded my images, is there any why to make this like 
if griview=="first" then

Comment: Does your 11 gridview has the same properties ? same column count, same parameters etc ?

Comment: yes same column count same parameters but each shows different images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  View row = convertView;
  RecordHolder holder = null;

  if (row == null) {
   LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
   row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

   holder = new RecordHolder();
   holder.imageItem = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
   row.setTag(holder);
  } else {
   holder = (RecordHolder) row.getTag();
  }


  holder.imageItem.setImageBitmap(data.get(position));
  return row;

 }
```

To implement a custom adapter for your grid view you need to implement the getView method in your adapter, in that method you have to pass position that is a int, this position is used to pass a array or list to create the Adapter from .

So All you can do is put your logic where you use position to populate your adapter from.

You can do it.

Else share your code here and let me see it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

11 grid views? why? is it all on one view? you can't share instance of adapter on more than one adapter view, it's very not recommended/impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You can make different types of views using:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return 1; //your type info here
}
```

So each element in adapter can have different view. Simply make some switch in getView method. 
Remember to also override getViewTypeCount so adapter will know how many types you have.